# DNN to Drupal 8 Url migration

Tags: url, dotnetnuke, drupal-8, data-migration

I am working on Drupal 8 migration project in which most of the work is done but my client want to preserve the old URL's from DNN-7 to Drupal 8. I have check the DNN database and didn't find any saved alias/Url in db table.

Current site having the URL's like:
`TheNews/EuropeNews/tabid/58/Id/5652/fromTab/58/currentIndex/39/Default.aspx`

And Drupal has their own URL system like:
`node\456` or `site.com\page-1`

Is there any way to get all the content URL's from DNN-7 from DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the variations of DNN generated URLS, and from the fact that it appears you were not using the "HumanFriendly" format, there isn't an easy way to get all variations out of the system.

The SiteMap file would be the closest thing you could use to get at least the full listing of primary URL's for the pages on the site.  That is accessed via /SiteMap.aspx for the site.